# Why doesn't my simple sql query work?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have the following query which works fine:

```
SET @var := 'test';

INSERT INTO yi5vu_roksprocket_items (module_id, provider, params)
VALUES ('122', 'simple', @var)
```

But if I change the variable such as written below it no longer works.

```
SET @var := '{"_article_title":"Simple Item 1","strips_item_title":"-none-","strips_item_image":"{'type':'mediamanager','path':'http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/fenrJmj.png','preview':'','link':'index.php?option=com_media&view=images&layout=default&tmpl=component&e_name=items_simple_1__params_strips_item_image'}","strips_item_link":"-default-","strips_item_description":"<html><body><div id=\"d_clip_button1\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-clipboard-text=\"[img]http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/fenrJmj.png[\/img]\" title=\"Copy.\"\">Copy<\/div>    <script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"ZeroClipboard.js\"><\/script><script type=\"text\/javascript\"> var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('d_clip_button1') );<\/script><\/body><\/html>","tabs_item_title":"-default-","tables_item_title":"-default-","lists_item_title":"-default-","mosaic_item_title":"-default-","grids_item_title":"-default-","quotes_item_description":"-default-","grids_item_description":"-default-","tables_item_description":"-default-","tabs_item_icon":"-default-","mosaic_item_description":"-default-","tabs_item_link":"-default-","lists_item_image":"-default-","quotes_item_image":"-default-","tables_item_image":"-default-","grids_item_image":"-default-","mosaic_item_image":"-default-","mosaic_item_link":"-default-","tabs_item_description":"-default-","grids_item_link":"-default-","tables_item_price":"-none-","tables_item_feature_1":"-none-","quotes_item_author":"-none-","lists_item_link":"-default-","mosaic_item_tags":"-article-","sliders_item_title":"-default-","features_item_title":"-default-","quotes_item_subtext":"-none-","tables_item_feature_2":"-none-","sliders_item_description":"-default-","headlines_item_image":"-default-","tables_item_feature_3":"-none-","lists_item_description":"-default-","quotes_item_link":"-default-","features_item_description":"-default-","quotes_item_direction":"-bottomleft-","features_item_image":"-default-","sliders_item_image":"-default-","headlines_item_link":"-default-","tables_item_feature_4":"-none-","tables_item_link":"-default-","features_item_link":"-default-","headlines_item_description":"-default-","sliders_item_link":"-default-","tables_item_link_text":"Buy Now"}';

INSERT INTO yi5vu_roksprocket_items (module_id, provider, params)
VALUES ('122', 'simple', @var)
```

What is causing this issue? I presume it's the single or back quotes, but I've tried every combination possible. The get a 1064 query error.

I simply want to take what's inside @var and inject it into params.

Comment: please provide the full error description

Comment: Probably due to single quote escaping issues.  Your string ends after "strips_item_image":"{  due to the single quotes around 'type'

Comment: Probably because you have single quotes within single quotes. You need to escape them.

Comment: If you just want to insert the json as a text string, you need to make sure your quotes are escaped. You have single quotes in your text string that break the string up into multiple strings. Take a look at the resource [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

Comment: What is the datatype of that field?  How many characters are in that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your string starts with a single-quote you cannot have any other single-quotes inside the string itself unless they are preceded by a back-slash.

So 'don't do this' is a bad string by 'don\'t do this' is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your example, I understand why now it didn\'t work :)